# Creative way to fix this bi-fold closet door top pivot hardware?

Tags: doors, replacement, closet

I've got some circa 1975 bi-fold closet doors with an oblong top slider that pops into the track when the bi-folds are all the way open, and then holds the door in the track once they are opened a bit:
[image]

I'm missing 2 of these, and I've tried searching online for a replacement, but all the bi-fold hardware I see seems to have circular sliders.

Does anyone have an idea what brand this is, how to find a replacement, or a creative way to make something work?

Comment: Replacement hardware kits are dirt cheap and install easily. Unless there's something about your situation that prevents doing so, I'd be going that route.

Comment: I don't think you will find identical replacements any more. Reproducing them would be difficult as well. Though I prefer a replacement as well, I think you are going to have to replace with a new kit.